# How to make a class in a another class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class

I want to make something like `bla.FooBarBaz` in JavaScript, but, `bla` is a class and `FooBarBaz` is a class, but INSIDE THE `bla` CLASS. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no nested classes in ES6 but yes, you can put a second class as a static property on another class, like this:

```
class Parent {
    //code
}
Parent.B = class {
   //code
};
```

or by using extra scope:

```
var dataClass;
{
    class D {
        constructor() { }
    }
    dataClass = class DataClass {
        constructor() { }
        method() {
            var a = new D();  // works fine
        }
    }
}
```

But with [the help of this proposed class](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields), you can write a single expression or declaration:

```
class Parent {
    //code
    static Child = class {
         //code
    }
};
```

Comment: And the usage??

Comment: parent = new Parent;
new parent.Child;

Comment: How to add a function inside that `new Parent.Child()`?

Comment: I can't use
```js
class bla {
  static FooBarBaz = class {
    function poof() {
      console.log("Poof!")
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try sth like this;

```
class bla {
   constructor() {
     this.FooBarBaz = new FooBarBaz();
   }
}
```

You can also use static

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).